# Pywhatkit query about virtual text base assistant

Tags: python

I am trying to build a text base virtual assistant but the problem is i don't know how to use pywhatkit playonyt and search command in such a way that the user gives input play.......(any song or video) and search(whatever they want to search) Please help if you can:)))

Code:

def take_command():

```
command = input("Tell me what would you like me to do").format()
song = pywhatkit.playonyt()

if command in ('play', 'search'):

    if command == 'play'+:
```

Comment: Did you notice you have an extra `+` at `'play'+:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pywhatkit

command = input("Tell me what would you like me to do: ").lower()

if "play" in command:
  pywhatkit.playonyt(command.replace("play ",""))
if "search" in command:
  pywhatkit.search(command.replace("search ",""))
```

It checks if command contains that particular words, if so, remove them and pass the rest of the phrase to the functions.